# Send current page url with serialized form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to send the URL of the current page along with the serialized form data. Now, the issue is that the URL with query params will also get parsed as form elements. As a stop gap solution i am replacing the "&" in the url with "_" and undoing it on the server side. Is there any better way/already existent way of doing this ?

Comment: you can use `url_encode`

Comment: encodeURI() wont remove the &. It will not encode reserved characters. decodeURIcomponent() will, but not sure how safe the encoded string will be while decoding complicated urls from php

Comment: ampersand encodes to %26, just do a replace

Comment: A replace is the simplest way. if you want to separate it you could perhaps send the data in another form such as a JSON string containing the URL and the params separately